# Using T-SQL, is it possible to insert records into a table without locking it?

Tags: t-sql

I have a process that inserts millions of records into a table.

While it's being executed, no other process can access that table. 
They have to wait a few minutes.  Unacceptable for web apps.

So, is there something like BULK INSERT that can be used between two sql tables ?

Thanks !

Comment: How are you executing your insert now?

Comment: How are you inserting the data? Are you using a SELECT INTO or INSERT SELECT?

Comment: INSERT INTO table (...) SELECT .....

Comment: By default, for inserting row, SQL Server will use row-level locking - it should **not** lock the whole table. Unless you're inserting more than 5'000 rows at once - then SQL Server will do **lock escalation** and lock the whole table. So if you want to insert rows during normal operations - do it in smaller batches - 4'000 rows at once.

Answer (score 3):

> So, is there something like BULK INSERT that can be used between two
>   sql tables ?

Yes there is... it's called [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) but it's a two step process to go from table to table:

Save the data locally:

```
execute xp_cmdshell 'bcp Northwind.dbo.Orders out c:\temp\Orders.txt -Sgalser01 -T -n'
```

Then bulk insert the saved file:

```
select * into Northwind.dbo.Orders2 from Northwind.dbo.Orders where 1=2
bulk insert Northwind.dbo.Orders2 from 'c:\temp\Orders.txt' 
     with (DATAFILETYPE  = 'native')
```