# How to insert/select without locking the destination table in MSSQL 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a process that needs to copy many rows, possibly tens or hundreds of thousands of them, from a staging table to another table where they'll be processed.

normally, I'd just say

```
insert into production_table select * from staging_table
```

But this statement could take an hour to run, so in order to not lock the processing table, we're using the following logic from a client app to move the next 1,000 rows over so that eventually all the rows make it to the production table:

```
do 
{
    max_id = select max(id) from production_table where jobid = YYY

    insert into production_table (jobid, ...) 
    select top 1000 jobid, ... from staging_table 
    where id > @max_id
    order by id asc

} while @row_count = 1000
```

I'm refactoring this process and I don't think this is the best way to do it. Is there a better (preferably transactionally safe) way to copy all the rows over in one go without locking the destination table?

Comment: This has been discussed earlier. See [this question...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236638/using-t-sql-is-it-possible-to-insert-records-into-a-table-without-locking-it)

Comment: I found that while researching, but it only describes bulk insert and not copying rows. I was hoping for a way to get it to work in one statement, or in an alternative, a SP that's transactionally safe to do the copying.

Comment: it describes how to use bulk insert to achieve what you asked for, doesn't it? and at first, it says that the other way round would be to insert in smaller batches to avoid table-lock.

Comment: The only answer suggests dumping the table to a file and then bulk inserting the table which is the exact opposite of what the OP asked to do since he's got data in a table already. So I hardly think that's a great answer. It also says that inserting in blocks of 4,000 should avoid locking the whole table, but that's essentially what I'm already doing but I'm doing it by making lots of calls from the client and if the client dies, I've got a half-committed transactions which I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use table partitioning?

1. Partition your destination table and your staging table on some column (like a date or incremental batchID).
2. When done with staging, switch the partition to the processing table.
3. After processing is done, you can switch the processed partition out and truncate it